# How to define OnKey event for a range?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to define OnKey event for escape button on a particular cells

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveCell.Value = "a" Or ActiveCell.Value = "b" Then
Application.OnKey "{ESC}", "unit"
```

And got the error popup - Macro is not available or is disabled...
Sub unit() works fine as a standalone procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit referecce works for me, try to use sheetname.subname, like Sheet6.unit:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value
    If ActiveCell.Value = "d" Or ActiveCell.Value = "e" Then
        Application.OnKey "{ESC}", "Sheet6.unit"
        Else
        Application.OnKey "{ESC}", ""
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub unit()
    Debug.Print "Unit!"
End Sub
```